# Query delta between two days

Tags: grafana, influxdb

i have energy consumption data that is shown in grafana in 1h blocks per day. The data gets written every 5 seconds and needs to be summed up.

[histogram](https://abload.de/img/e879070b-80a9-4ea6-b0gkr0.jpeg)

Thats the query:

[query](https://abload.de/img/6f1897e7-b4cf-4b5a-922jb2.jpeg)

I want to have another chart that shows the difference between actual consumption and consumption from yesterday in the same style.

The problem is i cant figure out how i could use the influxdb difference function correctly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt find any solution with the regular influxdb query language. But by using flux instead there is a solution

```
today = from(bucket: "piMeter") 
|> range(start: -31d) 
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "downsampled_energy" and r._field == "sum_Gesamt") 
|> fill(value: 0.0) 
|> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn:sum) 

yesterday = from(bucket: "piMeter") 
|> range(start: -62d, stop: -31d) 
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "downsampled_energy" and r._field == "sum_Gesamt")
|> fill(value: 0.0) 
|> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn:sum) 

join(tables:{today:today, yesterday:yesterday}, on:["_field"]) 
|> map(fn:(r) => ({
    _time: r._time_today,
    _value: r._value_today - r._value_yesterday,
   }))
|> fill(value: 0.0)
|> aggregateWindow(every:1d , fn:mean)
```